# Retrieving Dictionary from ViewState

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, viewstate

I'm having trouble with retrieving my dictionary object from ViewState. The ViewState object looks like it's populated correctly as shown below, however, when I try to set a dictionary object to the ViewState object it's Nothing.

ViewState("files") object via Immediate window:

?ViewState("files")

```
Count = 2
dict: Count = 2
(0): {[AITN2.deploy.cmd, file 1]}
(1): {[AITN2.SourceManifest.xml, file 2]}
```

Here's my code to set a dictionary object:

```
        Dim myFiles As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    If Not IsNothing(ViewState("files")) Then
        myFiles = CType(Session("files"), Dictionary(Of String, String))
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking ViewState, but retrieving data from Session.

Comment: OMG. It's late and another set of eyes really helped. Thanks so much.

Comment: I know the feeling, been there. Glad it was helpful. Btw, you don't have to declare `Dim myFiles As New Dictionary...`, no need to create a new object since variable is gong to be reassigned anyway. Simple ` Dim myFiles As Dictionary...` should do the trick